# Jquery show() doesn't work just before loading a new page on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

My site must do intensive work (fetching data from other sites) before a page is ready to be displayed.
So what happens is that user clicks a link, I show a spinning wheel gif, then when the page is ready it is loaded.

This doesn't work on safari browser (but does on Firefox): the wheel doesn't show at all. User clicks on the link, current page is still visible while waiting but whith no spinnign wheel:

Jquery code:

```
$( function() {
    $( '.show-spinning' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        $(".spinning-wheel").show()
    } );
} );
```

Css code:

```
.spinning-wheel {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("../images/spinning.gif");
}
```

Container html code:

```
<div class="spinning-wheel"> </div>
```

Link code that is supposed to trigger the .show() of the container:

```
<a href="/otherpage" class="show-spinning">Link to other page</a>
```

This does work when I test for example with:

```
<a href="#" class="show-spinning">test</a>
```

It's only when the link is real and sending to another page that the .show() does nothing, on safari.

Is there a trick or another method to have this work on safari ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the ins-and-outs of safari to be sure, but it would seem that once a page refresh cycle has started it doesn't see the point in continuing to process javascript on the page that's about to get unloaded.  If so, it has a point, since the new page could come in at any time and you wouldn't want the browser stuck on a long-running script from a page that's supposed to be going away...

I think your options are to use an `href='#'` link and include redirection to the new page in the click handler (after showing the spinner), or to move toward an SPA type approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could cancel the link click, display your spinning wheel and then make the redirect in javascript.

```
$( function() {
    $( '.show-spinning' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".spinning-wheel").show()
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    } );
} );
```

Could it be a css problem? Either the fixed position is behaving differently in safari or .show() isn't adding display: block;

Maybe adding a class to your spinner

```
.spinning-wheel.hidden {
    display:none;
}

.spinning-wheel{
    display: block;
}
```

Then remove the `hidden` class on click

```
$( function() {
    $( '.show-spinning' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".spinning-wheel").removeClass('hidden');
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Could it be a css problem? Either the fixed position is behaving differently in safari or .show() isn't adding display: block;

Maybe adding a class to your spinner

.spinning-wheel.hidden {
    display:none;
}

.spinning-wheel{
    display: block;
}

Comment: All of those ideas might be sensible, except according to the question this works as coded when the link has `href="#"`... which means it pretty much has to be the page redirect that's interfering

Comment: That's why cancelling the redirect with preventDefault(); and showing the spinner before the redirect should work

Comment: @Vincent - No, actually it's why that *doesn't* work.  Because of the refresh the event handler isn't being run; you can't fix that by having the event handler cancel the refresh because **the event handler isn't being run**.  What you're saying would perhaps be true if for some reason Safari ran the script but just refused to update the DOM, but that's not what's observed.